# How to display every list item with in viewpager in android

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

First sorry for my bad English and this is simple question but i google it no solution found i found this is only place to getting solution ,In my JSON Object contains lats of images and images title and description  ,I my first pages i want to display image title and image after click the image bundle the data and display all field their,when i trying to this in list view its working perfect ,but i need to display this in view page ,like below screen i need to display like this ,my json update every hours getting new images please any one guide me how to do this ,after swipe up i get next images from json 
here below my screen
[image]

Comment: you can make custom layout and put this in view pager as viewpager layout.

Comment: if you don't mine any reference link for this@nidhi